# check memory allocation line by line in Julia

Tags: memory, julia, profile

I want to check memory allocation in each line of my code. I used `@time`, and I got 
`5.381438 seconds (2.19 M allocations: 809.021 MiB, 1.08% gc time)`

what does `(2.19 M allocations: 809.021 MiB, 1.08% gc time)` mean?

My code for some Input is out of memory and I know there is a problem with memory allocation, How can I check memory allocation line by line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The total amount of allocation can be measured with `@time` and `@allocated`, and specific lines triggering allocation can often be inferred from profiling via the cost of garbage collection that these lines incur.
>
> **However, sometimes it is more efficient to directly measure the amount of memory allocated by each line of code.**

- [Memory allocation analysis](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/profile/#Memory-allocation-analysis-1)

> To measure allocation line-by-line, start Julia with the `--track-allocation=<setting>` command-line option.
>
> When you quit Julia, the cumulative results are written to text files with `.mem` appended after the file name, residing in the same directory as the source file.
>
> Each line lists the total number of bytes allocated.

Comment: I have jupyter notebook how can I run `--track-allocation` ?